# Running SingleSpa Micro-frontend in Dev standalone mode with no Internet access

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, overriding, micro-frontend, single-spa

Need a piece of advice regarding a good way to override dependencies of Single-Spa running Micro frontend in standalone mode.

The point is that I need to run my Micro frontend in dev standalone mode under Webpack Dev server in an environment where there is no Internet access. It fails as React Single-spa includes a number of libs from a public CDN.

Looking for a solution, I've seen it is possible to configure an overriding in some way, but didn't come to a good recipe. Prefer picking all external deps from node_modules.

Next external deps are in index.html, which generates Single-spa in dev mode:

```
"imports": {
    "single-spa": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/single-spa/lib/system/single-spa.dev.js",
    "@corp/myapp": "/corp-myapp.js"
  }
// all from cdn.jsdelivr.net
import-map-overrides.js
fetch.umd.js
polyfill.min.js
runtime.min.js
system.js
amd.js
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply download the files and put them in the `public` folder of your root-config.
After that you can reference them like so:
`"single-spa": "/single-spa.dev.js"`

Instead of downloading them manually you can also install the corresponding npm packages and copy the files to the public folder through a script. Or Host them on a separate server in the network.

Comment: SingleSpa generates index.html automatically, so there is no direct control on dependencies it inserts into.

Comment: Yes it gets generated by the create single-spa cli tool. But you can change the index.html manually

Comment: It would be a trivial case. I ask because it is not a trivial case. There is no index.html as a file. The root looks like:

```
import singleSpaReact from 'single-spa-react'

const reactLifecycles = singleSpaReact({
  React,
  ReactDOM,
  rootComponent: App,
  errorBoundary(err, info, props) {
    return GlobalErrorBoundary
  },
})

export { bootstrap, mount, unmount }
```

And index.html is generated indirectly, in memory, so there is no direct control on it.

So, Singlespa creates it under the hood.

I look for the way to override dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/single-spa/standalone-single-spa-webpack-plugin

You can inject custom scripts with the `src/index.ejs` file.